# antd select add new item with multiple mode

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
antd 3.x
```

I need add a new item into the select in `multiple` mode

Default data

```
var data = [ { id: 1, name: 'John' }, { id:2, name: 'Nancy' }  ]
```

Ant select:

```
<Select>
{users.map((user)=> <Option value={user.id}>{user.name}</Option>) }
</Select>
```

`tags` mode doesn't support `value` attribute

I want to add new item like `tags mode`. I will handle the values in backend.

Any help?

Comment: The `Option` component needs a `key` prop, e.g. `<Option key={user.id} value={user.id} label={user.name} />`.