# In AntD how to combine the functionality of TreeSelect with 'tags' mode of Select?

Tags: javascript, select, antd, react-dropdown-tree-select

How to combine Ant Design [Checkable TreeSelect](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/?theme=compact#components-tree-select-demo-checkable) functionality of autocompleting tree select with the ability of adding new tags based on un-listed input, that is provided in [Select with `mode="tags"`](https://ant.design/components/select/?theme=compact#components-select-demo-tags)? Btw, I need to use in JSON tree format as implemented in [this example](https://ant.design/components/tree-select/?theme=compact#components-tree-select-demo-multiple).

I'v tried to add `mode="tags"` option to `<TreeSelect />` - it activates in-listed tags input, but crashes TreeSelect features.

I'v also researched that [React guys think that it's not cool to have a "tags" mode in TreeSelect](https://github.com/react-component/select/blob/423f860b8582e8d105ce67d189da096db36c0ba6/src/generate.tsx#L426). Sry guys, but I need exactly that!) But I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: As I have researched, the same question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675979/antd-select-add-new-item-with-multiple-mode but has no clear answer for me.

Comment: @ramamoorthy-villi maybe you can help? It seems that you have knowledge in this field.

Comment: @jesper-we it also seems that maybe you could help as well. Sorry for hesitating you.